# align div close to posts

Tags: css, html

i own a blog url http://www.rayaaskart.com/ . I placed a code for social sharing button . you can see it is aligned to left side of the window on my site. i want to align near to blog posts . how i can do it by modifying the css . i included the style code along with this message.

```
 <style>
.float_sharer 
{
 text-align:center;
 width:70px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color:white;
 padding : 10px;
 position: fixed;
 box-shadow:0 0 10px #999 inset;
 top: 200px;
 left: 0px;
 z-index: 10;
 }
 </style>
```

Comment: What do you mean by '**near** to blog posts'?

Comment: if you want to keep the position fixed, just change top to top: 214px; and left to left: 72px;

Comment: @Etienne and have it horribly broken on small screens... ;)

Comment: Sure. I mean the best practice is to change the HTML First

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `left: 0px;` to `left: 20px;`...20px is an example ...change it to fit your need

Comment: this won't work since as soon as you use a value other than auto the viewport will be used as reference. This way it will break on resizing.

Comment: @Anandraj this will break on small screens and overlap with your content (resize your browser to see the effect). Why don't you try my solution instead?

Answer (score 0):

Omit the `left: 0px;` so it's positioned in it's original position and instead add `margin-left:-100px;` to your style to move it 100px to the left (70px width + 20px padding + 10px margin = 100px).

To nicely align it with your maincontent, also omit the `top` declaration and replace it with `margin-top:8px;` (the same margin you give to your `#main-wrapper`).